# What is Falcor for React.js?

Tags: javascript, architecture, reactjs

tell me please? what is [Falcor](https://netflix.github.io/falcor/starter/what-is-falcor.html)?
Is it somthing like Flux or Reflux for React.js? 
Falcor - is it *model*? 
If I use Falcor, I should not use Flux or Reflux?

Comment: From the description: it's a middleware that sits on the backend between your application and your data and allows you to query for subsets of the data.

Comment: so, is it API for requests ?

Comment: Can i use Falcor with Flux or Reflux? Or it does not need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an api or data model that helps to solve data duplication and the large numbers of requests when your app is touching many separate yet related backends.

It's only tangentially related to the Flux pattern in that its being promoted as a good fit with applications built with react or other spa architectures.

A good starting resource to understand your "What is it" is talked about in [this](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/08/28/getting-started-with-falcor/) blog post